# iterate json object data using map along with key

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have trying to get collection of data from json object using map and assign key, pair reference in loop but its not working out for me. I can read value in iterations but I need to assign to key and value where I need help. its not recognising "key" and "value"

```
 var j1 = _preDefineAnswerOptions.map(function(item){
    return ["key": item.preDefineAnswerId, "value": item.text];
 });
```

### data-source structure

[image]

Comment: Change `return ["key": item.preDefineAnswerId, "value": item.text];` to `return {"key": item.preDefineAnswerId, "value": item.text};`

Comment: thanks it worked... if you paste your answer then I can add plus point on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return an object. Use `{}` around the key and value.

```
var j1 = _preDefineAnswerOptions.map(function(item){
 return {"key": item.preDefineAnswerId, "value": item.text};
});
```